# Error while using KMeans and GUnicorn inside docker

Tags: python, docker, scikit-learn, gunicorn, k-means

I am running KMeans clustering inside a docker using GUnicorn and getting this in the docker logs:

```
2023-07-27 04:36:32,772 INFO Clustering Stared without issues !
2023-07-27 04:36:32,772 INFO Preview of data we are working with:
2023-07-27 04:36:32,782 INFO
   pressure   distance  cloudcover  humidity  windspeedKmph  percpmm  tempC
0    900.00  22.429714        40.5     30.93           3.57    19.24  33.50
1    866.67  24.261809         0.0     16.98           3.57    12.41  32.62
2    983.33  22.970385         0.0     23.26           2.71     4.30  33.06
3    916.67  23.144274         4.5     35.12           3.57    13.67  36.12
4    883.33  21.591553         0.0     27.44           3.57    34.58  31.31
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.
[2023-07-27 04:36:34 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) was sent code 139!
[2023-07-27 04:36:34 +0000] [2551] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2551
[2023-07-27 04:36:37 +0000] [2551] [INFO] Started server process [2551]
[2023-07-27 04:36:37 +0000] [2551] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2023-07-27 04:36:37 +0000] [2551] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

Specifications of the hardware:

```
Architecture: X86_64
CPU: Intel Xeon Gold
```

The bracketed logs are being generated by GUnicorn; the non-bracketed ones are being generated by me. The reason to use GUnicorn is that I also have another functionality that runs from the main file and needs to be run in parallel with KMeans.

I researched online and got the following solutions:

```
1. Install numpy and scipy from conda-forge, instead of pip 
(Not possible for me since I have no authority to make changes to the Dockerfile)

2. Change the environment variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS = 1 (Does not work)

3. OpenBLAS has issues with CPUs having more than 64 cores (Could not verify), so change n_jobs=64 
(Have not tried out yet)

4. Use MiniBatchKMeans instead of KMeans (Does not work)
```

What should I do?